# Onclick not working for enabling read only field in IE8 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have simple requirement to enable the readonly text field on click and enter the values in it.

for this i followed following js

```
function enableField(){
document.getElementById("recordname").readOnly = false;  
}
```

Html code is

```
<input id="recordname" cssClass="Gry999"  maxLength="35"  readonly="true" onclick="enableField()" name="recordname"  onkeypress="return validateCustomize(event);"/>
```

In All browsers (firefox, chrome, ie 9) ,this code is working as expected,
but in IE8 - i need to click two times to enter values ( in a first click the textfield is gettign focus but cannot enter values, its behave like readyonly)

i have tried the jquery also(after removing onclik attr from input field) but no help

```
$(document).ready(function() {                 
     $('#recordname').on('click',function() {           
     $('.jqueryclickcls').attr('readonly', false);   
  });
});
```

**Update:**
The same  `document.getElementById("recordname").readOnly = false;`  code works when this code triggered from any other control ,like while clicking on another link enable text field

```
function enableField(){
    document.getElementById("recordname").readOnly = false;  
document.getElementById("recordname").focus();
    }
<a onclick="enableField()" >Enable Field</a>
```

after this i can type the values??!!

Comment: Your question is tagged jQuery, but are you actually using it? (i.e. is a purely jQuery answer fine?)

Comment: i have tried jquery also, i''l post that code now

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery in order to set the field to be disabled (i.e. read-only):

```
function disableField(){
    $("#recordname").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function enableField(){
    $("#recordname").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

This is pretty straighforward and works for me on IE also.

Comment: I don't think disabled fields' values are submitted when the form is submitted (while values of readonly fields are) -- if that's an issue here. Otherwise, for later versions of jQuery the recommended way (in the [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop)) to enable/disable is `.prop("disabled",true)` or `.prop("disabled",false)`

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that you need the values when submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, it is "`readOnly`" and not "`readonly`"

try

```
document.getElementById("recordname").setAttribute('readOnly', '');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('champ').removeAttribute('readOnly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("recordname").disabled = false;
```